# Is there an efficient way to form this block matrix with numpy or scipy?

Tags: matrix, scipy, numpy

Is there an efficient way to form this block matrix with numpy or scipy?

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
\mathbf{B} & \mathbf{0} & \cdots & \mathbf{0}\\
\mathbf{AB} & \mathbf{B} & \cdots & \mathbf{0}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\mathbf{A}^{N-1}\mathbf{B} & \mathbf{A}^{N-2}\mathbf{B} & \cdots & \mathbf{B}\\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Here, $\mathbf{A}$ is $N\times N$, $\mathbf{B}$ is $N\times M$. They are the matrices for a dynamical system $x=\mathbf{A}x+\mathbf{B}u$.

I could propagate the matrix using `np.block()`, but I hope there's a way of forming this matrix that can scale based on $N$. I was thinking maybe Kronecker product `np.kron()` can help, but I can't think of a way. Any advice would help, and if anyone knows what this matrix is called please let me know.

I can do the following to generate a hardcoded solution for $N=3$.

```
N = 3
A = np.random.random((N, N))
B = np.random.random((N, 1))
print("A:", A)
print("B:", B)
np.block([ [B, np.zeros((B.shape[0], B.shape[1]*(N-1)))],
           [A@B, B, np.zeros((B.shape[0], B.shape[1]*(N-1-1)))],
           [np.linalg.matrix_power(A,N-1)@B, np.linalg.matrix_power(A,N-1-1)@B, B]
         ] )
```

output:

```
array([[0.53736681, 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.05086935, 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.42558792, 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.42032564, 0.53736681, 0.        ],
       [0.62266266, 0.05086935, 0.        ],
       [0.43163605, 0.42558792, 0.        ],
       [0.94690357, 0.42032564, 0.53736681],
       [0.76683544, 0.62266266, 0.05086935],
       [0.73345624, 0.43163605, 0.42558792]])
```

What I am hoping to achieve is an efficient way to generate such a matrix that scales with $N$, and I am able to do it with `np.block()` and list but it just seems to be not efficient for me.

```
mat_list = [] 
for i in range(N): # generate row
    tmp = []
    for j in range(N): # loop through A^j*B
        if j <= i:
            tmp.append(np.linalg.matrix_power(A,i-j)@B)
    if i < N-1:
        tmp.append(np.zeros((B.shape[0], B.shape[1]*(N-1-i))))
    mat_list.append(tmp)

np.block(mat_list)
```

output:

```
array([[0.53736681, 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.05086935, 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.42558792, 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.42032564, 0.53736681, 0.        ],
       [0.62266266, 0.05086935, 0.        ],
       [0.43163605, 0.42558792, 0.        ],
       [0.94690357, 0.42032564, 0.53736681],
       [0.76683544, 0.62266266, 0.05086935],
       [0.73345624, 0.43163605, 0.42558792]])
```

Comment: Two questions: (1) By `scales with N` do you mean $O(N)$ in big-O notation?  If so, that's impossible since you want to construct a full matrix of size $N^2 \times NM$. Simply touching every entry is $O(N^3)$. (2) Do you really need to explicitly construct this matrix? If you just need to, for example, perform a matrix-vector-product there might be ways to do that more efficiently.

Comment: @LedHead (1) no I want a function that takes in N to construct the matrix. (2) that'll be what I prefer, and that was why I mentioned Kronecker product which might be able to do it, but I haven't figured how.

Answer (score 7):

The code proposed by the OP can indeed made be more efficient, mainly by noting the fact that to form the sequence $A^i B$, with $i=0\,\dots,N$ you do not have to compute $A^i$ at each step, but you can exploit the fact that $A^i B = A\,(A^{i-1}B)$, reusing the result of the previous step.

My proposed implementation is

```
import numpy as np

N = 3
M = 1

A = np.random.random((N, N))
B = np.random.random((N, M))

X = np.zeros((N ** 2, N * M))
rsl = slice(0, N)
X[rsl, :M] = B
for i in range(1, N):
    rsl_p, rsl = rsl, slice(i * N, (i + 1) * N)
    X[rsl, :M] = A @ X[rsl_p, :M]
    X[rsl, M : (i + 1) * M] = X[rsl_p, : i * M]
```

This question is more related to programming that computational science, so I add some general remarks, useful for a novice programmer.

1. never blindly translate mathematical expressions into code: think algorithmically.

   ```
   X = np.linalg.matrix_power(A,i)@B
   ```

   is much slower than

   ```
   X=B; 
   for j in range(i): X = A*X
   ```

   if $M \ll N$

   (exercise: compute operation count for both code fragments).
2. whenever possible reuse previous calculations.
3. pre-allocate output matrices, and do not store intermediate results in temp. matrices

Comment: thanks, based on my benchmark this is about 10 times as fast as what I had. I am guessing this is already optimal solution for constructing such as matrix.

Comment: @drerD glad that this was useful to you. The proposed implementation should also have better asymptotics with respect to the old one, so I expect that the speed-up should increase with $N$.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to explicitly construct the entire matrix, then Stefano M's answer is your best bet. If, however, you don't really need the whole matrix, but just need to be able to perform a matrix-vector-product (MVP), then you might want to consider the following approach. Based on your comments it's unclear to me if this helps you, and I realize this doesn't technically answer your question, but I thought I'd post it just in case.

Suppose you want to calculate the MVP:

$\left(
\begin{array}{c}y_1 \\ y_2 \\ \vdots \\ y_N \end{array}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
  B & 0 & ... & 0 \\ 
  A B  & B & ... & 0 \\
   \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
  A^{N-1} B &   A^{N-2} B & ... & B
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_N \end{array}
\right)$

where $x_i$'s are size $Mx1$ and known and we want to calculate $y_i$'s which
are size $Nx1$ and unknown. This
can be expressed block-by-block as

$\begin{array}{lll}
  y_i & = & \sum\limits_{j=1}^{i} A^{i-j} B x_j\\
           & = & B x_i + \sum\limits_{j=1}^{i-1} A^{i-j} B x_j \\
           & = & B x_i + A \sum\limits_{j=1}^{i-1} A^{(i-1)-j} B x_j \\
           & = & B x_i + A y_{i-1}\\
\end{array}$

for $i=1,2,...,N$. (The last step works if we assume $y_0 \equiv \mathbf{0}^{[N \times 1]}$.)

This should be much faster than using the full dense matrix.

Example Python code:

```py
import numpy as np

def mvp(A,B,x):

    n=A.shape[0]
    m=B.shape[1]

    # assume that x is 1D array of size [n*m]

    y=np.zeros( (n*n) )

    y[:n] = B @ x[:m]
    for i in range(1,n):
        y[i*n:(i+1)*n] = B @ x[i*m:(i+1)*m] + A @ y[(i-1)*n:i*n]

    return y

N = 3
M = 1

A = np.random.random((N, N))
B = np.random.random((N, M))
x=np.random.random( (N*M) )

y=mvp(A,B,x)
```

Comment: thanks, that's exactly how the original dynamical equations get turned into the matrix. When you mentioned MVP, I was thinking you might be thinking of doing the following, for example N=3, M=1 case:

Comment: $\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
  B & 0 & 0 \\ 
  A B  & B & 0 \\
  A^2 B & AB & B
\end{array}
\right) =  \left( \left(\begin{array}{c}0 \\ 0 \\ A \end{array} \right) \left(\begin{array}{c}A \  I \ 0 \end{array} \right) + \left(\begin{array}{c}0 \\ A \\ 0 \end{array} \right) \left(\begin{array}{c}I \  0 \ 0 \end{array} \right) + \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
  I & 0 & 0 \\ 
  0  & I & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & I
\end{array}
\right) \right) \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
  B & 0 & 0 \\ 
  0  & B & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & B
\end{array}
\right)$

Comment: This is something I just derived, but I think there might be efficient way of utilizing matrix vector products to create such a matrix, especially without for loop.

Comment: One thing I just tried is scipy.linalg.toeplitz([range(N)], np.hstack([[1], np.zeros(N-1) ])), which produces a matrix of the powers for A, then if I can just map it, then multiply by the diagonal matrix of Bs, it'll be quite efficient.

Comment: A question I probably should have asked earlier: how large of $N$ and $M$ are you typically dealing with?

Comment: depends on the dynamical system matrices A,B. N can be 10 or larger, M can be larger than 1. Actually the N here doesn't necessarily have to be the same as matrix A's dimension. So N can be larger than 100, I should've parametrize N as $N_h$. So it's actually, \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
  B & 0 & ... & 0 \\ 
  A B  & B & ... & 0 \\
   \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
  A^{N_h -1} B &   A^{N_h-2} B & ... & B
\end{array}
\right). And the resultant matrix can be 1000x1000.

Comment: So your overall matrix is on the order of maximum 100s of elements by 10s of elements or so? In that case I can't imagine you're going to do much better than @Stefano M's answer. Is constructing this matrix really hurting you in computational time?

Comment: It’s probably only used once. I was hoping there’s some smart efficient way to generate this matrix with MVP or matrix decomposition, not just populating it with for loop.